# I want to redirect users upon login and filter out their details in a template

Tags: python, django

Here is the statement verifying whether a user exists.

```
if user is not None:
    auth.login(request, user)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/studentloggedin/')
```

Here is the template I define for the users to be routed to. Student is a foreign key to user in the admin and registration is a foreign key to student model. Student is also a foreign key to other models and I want to query out everything related to that user.

```
def studentloggedin(request):
    registration = Registration.objects.get()
    student = Student.objects.filter(registration=registration)
    context = {
        'registration': registration,
        'student': student,
    }
    return render(request, "studentloggedin.html", context)
```

And here is one of the fields that I'm querying in the html template:

```
{{ student.previous_school }}
```

But no information displaying upon login right now. I don't really know why.

Comment: Not sure if a typo but `Registration.objects.get()` needs to be supplied with lookup parameters

Comment: Also `Student.objects.filter` returns a QuerySet not a student object. (No query sent to the database yet as you can chain more things like `order_by` etc. Use that when expecting multiple results. In this case `Student.objects.get(registration=registration)` assuming `registration` is unique.